# a new user first login into website

Tags: c#, javascript

i am trying to register a person and verify him.After verification whenever the new user logins into my website for the first time i want him to redirect to a Default.aspx page else his dashboard.
So how can i know whether a person has logged into my website for the first time?
can we know it through web?

Comment: @PhonicUK — What should he have tried?

Comment: If he's succeeded in making a system that can register and verify users, one would hope he'd already made some kind of attempt before asking.

Answer (score 4):

Add a (boolean) column (e.g. `seen_welcome_msg`) in the users table in the database.

When a user logs in, if it is set to `false`, redirect the user.

When the user visits `Default.aspx`, set the column value to `true`

Comment: If user is not logged in how you will know which user is this?

Comment: @Adil — If the user isn't logged in at all, then they certainly are not "logged into my website for the first time", which is what the question is asking to detect.

Comment: Got it my mistake to understand

Comment: if the user is not able to login into website then he is not a valid user